# how to use epoll with data->ptr, instead of data.fd?

Tags: epoll

I'm writing an application using epoll and large amount of fd's.
in order to improve the searches of fd to application relevant DB, I want to pass to epoll application info, such as index in DB array.
I thought of using the data->ptr (epoll_data_t --> *ptr), as far as I understood, I can give pointer that holds the fd and private information from the application layer, but couldn't found any documents or examples.

I found this post, which seems to be relevant, but there is no implementation example...
[How to use epoll_event data.ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916707/how-to-use-epoll-event-data-ptr)

Thanks

Comment: Here's another related question that might help better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325748/about-epoll-ctl

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can put whatever you want in `data`. It's not used by epoll itself, it just returns it when the event occurs on the fd specified in the argument list.

Comment: Hi Barmer - Thanks for your comment.
I'm missing out something here, the epoll data struct is UNION, looks like that: 
typedef union epoll_data
{
  void *ptr;
  int fd;
  uint32_t u32;
  uint64_t u64;
} epoll_data_t; 
--> meaning that if I'm writing something to *ptr, and then writing to the fd, it will overwrite the *ptr value (it's union...) 
what is the correct way to write to the *ptr, and keep the fd?

Comment: You don't need to keep the fd in `epoll_data`. The fd that's being polled is the third argument to `epoll_ctl()`, not the one in the structure. If _you_ need to know the fd, put it in the structure that `ptr` points to.